# current cell with event click full_calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Hi i'm getting some events and rendering them in background like this

```
eventSources: [{
  {
    url:        '/appointments/non_working_times.json',
    type:       'GET',
    rendering:  'background',
    color:      'black !important',
    className:  'unavailable'
  }],
```

Then as you can see the calendar loads with some color black events

[image: background and appointment events]

Now what I want to do is show an alert when a cell is clicked and this one is with black color with `dayClick event`... I mean something like this:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) { 
 alert('current cell is not available') //just if the current cell color is black
},
```

I have tried validating with the current class with `$(this)` but I can't see any class that is coloring the cell

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple... It could be useful for somebody

```
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    if (jsEvent.target.classList[1] == 'unavailable'){
      alert('Espacio no disponible')
    } else {
      show_appointment_summary(date)
    }
  },
```